# calling program in conda env with subprocess

Tags: python, anaconda, subprocess, conda, environment

I am trying to run a program (`clinker`) from a python script using `subprocess` - it should generate a html file containing a plot:

version 1:

```
cmd = f'clinker {files}-p "{work_dir}/plot.html"'
subprocess.run(cmd, 
               check=True, 
               capture_output=True)
```

version 2:

```
subprocess.run(cmd, 
               shell=True, 
               check = True,
               capture_output=True)
```

both output:

```
CalledProcessError: Command 'clinker "C:/Users/u03132tk/.spyder-py3/file_name1.gbk" "C:/Users/u03132tk/.spyder-py3/file_name2.gbk" -p "C:/Users/u03132tk/.spyder-py3/plot.html"' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

When I enter `clinker "C:/Users/u03132tk/.spyder-py3/file_name1.gbk" "C:/Users/u03132tk/.spyder-py3/file_name2.gbk" -p "C:/Users/u03132tk/.spyder-py3/plot.html"` in my anaconda prompt with the env activated the command works fine.

I suspect that I need to find the clinker `.exe` filepath in my env file and replace "`clinker`" in my `subprocess` command with the `.exe` path.  However, I also suspect I'll have file permission errors and, in general, it feels like a very hacky approach.  Is there a better way?  In case it's relevant, I am using spyder in my base env, pointing to the python exe in the env:

[image: spyder preferences panel]

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `cmd = f'clinker {files}-p "{work_dir}/plot.html"'` Try `cmd = ["conda", "run", "-n", "pip_env", "clinker", f"{files}", "-p",  f"{work_dir}/plot.html"]`